# Listing all pods ports

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath

So, i am trying to pull a list of all internal pods ports from all namespaces and i have the following command which is working but just for a specific pod/namespace/rc.

```
PS C:\Users\> kubectl get -o jsonpath="{.spec.template.spec.containers[*]['ports','name']}" deployments rke2-coredns-rke2-coredns -n kube-system
[{"containerPort":53,"name":"udp-53","protocol":"UDP"},{"containerPort":53,"name":"tcp-53","protocol":"TCP"}] coredns
```

How can make the command work for all pods in deployments?

Thanks,
EM

Comment: Be aware though that ports don't actually represent actually listening and exposed ports.

Comment: If you have a better command that can pull internal ports from all pods would be great. thanks

Comment: You cannot, any application can listen any port and kubernetes cannot know which.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the `--all-namespaces` parameter (or `-A`) :

```bash
kubectl get -o jsonpath="{.spec.template.spec.containers[*]['ports','name']}" deployments --all-namespaces
```

If you want to retrieve a specific `deployment` this will not work as a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't return any results

PS C:\Users\> kubectl get -o jsonpath="{.spec.template.spec.containers[*]['ports','name']}" deployments --all-namespaces
PS C:\Users\>

Answer (score 0):

To get the `ports` and `name` from all pods in every `deployments`, you can run the following `kubectl` command:

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.template.spec.containers[*]['ports','name']}"
```

Tested on:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.1", GitCommit:"8f94681cd294aa8cfd3407b8191f6c70214973a4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-01-18T15:58:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24+", GitVersion:"v1.24.17-eks-8cb36c9", GitCommit:"b114b128d961e18fed9242aed57f37f289bc740f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-11-22T21:53:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```